# Indoor avocado plant - What is wrong with the leaves?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, avocado

I have this avocado tree which i have taken care of since i planted a stone, and it started growing. The plant is around two years old now and for a lot of the time i have had issues with the leaves "dying/burning", as the pictures below show. The older the leafes are, the worse they become, it usually takes a few months before they start showing signs of issues. The top leafes are now a few months old and have started getting some "burn marks" in the end, but nothing compared to those in the bottom.

So the question is, why does this happen and what can i do about it?

The tree is planted indoor in Norway, which gives it many months without sunlight to speak of. I have had it under a plant light for the last ~8 months, so it gets around 12 hours daily of plant light, and also indirect sunlight now in the summer months.

The tree is planted in mulch, so i do not think the kind of soil used, is any issue. The pot used is the largest i had available at the time, allthough it is in plastic. It has a container for water in the bottom, so water does run through it when i water, but i cannot let water run through for too long.

I water it with regular tap water, salt in the water is a non issue here at 2,5 ºdH.

I have not been giving it any particular extra nutrients as i have read that one should be careful with that as it might cause leaves to "burn".

So the tree does not exactly appear to be dying, but it would be nice if i could help it to thrive better than it is currently doing.

[image: The whole tree]

[image: Zooming in on a leaf]